# How to remove duplicates from dynamic column through KQL

Tags: azure, cloud, kql, azure-monitor

we are trying to setup alerts for application(container) logs through kQL Queries in Azure cloud.  we are running following query to track error and remove duplicates.

```
    let ContainerIdList = KubePodInventory
    | where ContainerName contains "custom-app-logger"
    | where Namespace has "devns"
    | where ClusterId =~ '/subscriptions/12345-xyzl-4e12-bc3a-5c7859365342636/resourcegroups/rg-aks-dev-dev/providers/Microsoft.ContainerService/managedClusters/aksdevcluster'
    | distinct ContainerID;
     ContainerLog 
    | where ContainerID in (ContainerIdList)
    | where LogEntry !has "SRV1174"
    | where LogEntry has "| E |" or LogEntry has "| F |"
    | where LogEntry !contains "the I/O interface definition of project" 
    | where LogEntry !contains "the I/O interface definition of cuc" 
    | project LogEntrySource, LogEntry, TimeGenerated 
    | order by TimeGenerated desc
    | top 1000 by LogEntry
    | render table
    | distinct LogEntry
```

however its not removing the duplicates. if you see the log output below except first and last one, all others are same only with different timestamp in it. please find the log output screenshot below.

[![enter image description here][1]][1]

could you please help me how can we remove duplicates with actual error, if it is same error with different time stamp in it, need to pick the latest one.

Comment: Note that we prefer a technical style of writing here. We gently discourage greetings, hope-you-can-helps, thanks, advance thanks, notes of appreciation, regards, kind regards, signatures, please-can-you-helps, chatty material and abbreviated txtspk, pleading, how long you've been stuck, voting advice, meta commentary, etc. Just explain your problem, and show what you've tried, what you expected, and what actually happened.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have reproduced in my environment and got expected results as below:

Firstly, taken a simple table like below:

```
LogEntry

0|2023-07-23 11:40:50|b|abc
0|2023-07-23 11:42:50|b|abc
0|2023-07-23 12:40:50|c|xyz
0|2023-07-23 14:40:50|d|bnm
```

[image]

Then I have used below query to remove duplicates:

```
let x = datatable(LogEntry: string)
[
    "0|2023-07-23 11:40:50|b|abc",
    "0|2023-07-23 11:42:50|b|abc",
    "0|2023-07-23 12:40:50|c|xyz",
    "0|2023-07-23 14:40:50|d|bnm"
]
| extend SplitLog = split(LogEntry, "|")
| project C1 = SplitLog[0], cc=SplitLog[1],C2 = todatetime(SplitLog[1]), C3 = SplitLog[2], UV = SplitLog[3];
x
| summarize arg_max(C2,*) by tostring(UV)
| project-away UV
| project Log = strcat(tostring(C1), "|", cc, "|", C3, "|", UV1)
```

[image]

Output:

[image]

[Fiddle](https://dataexplorer.azure.com/clusters/help/databases/SampleMetrics?query=H4sIAAAAAAAAA4WQT2uEMBDF736KwZMpEZK4pWDZU+itt6KXRUrMBrH4Z4lTqks+fGdbKx5amlxekt+8vJnOIcxwhLNB2nXnkuexeRrQLzlM6NuhYdEpAlqxCEqoLBUPqcpAyvwg8nsR6mBqG/M/EPUPolYXG+bl+jtyWJFzqIc+jqoogJvRDWd4uXQtUlyKP93kFp1DHGJG4MWPb84iaEnMD34SFQdrj9tZVlwrAnCkKThse5fs3hgHne3LFZUX5f4mqx6jmb6b3vve+PbqwPjmtTdzohW/Y1Av5P09zaQod8FS82EWMttFXftBbw0mW5WW7KupW/BV6GwVRSnZJ9dHqtDHAQAA).

Split the `LogEntry`  column by pipes(**|**) and create new columns. Then summarize it by UniqueValues(UV) and take the maximum of Timestamp(C2)  and remove Unique Value column(which you will get extra column) then `concat` it back with Pipe symbol like I have done. Try to follow above example to get desired result as I have got.

**EDIT:**

```
ContainerIdList
    | extend SplitLog = split(LogEntry, "|")
    | project C1 = SplitLog[0], cc=SplitLog[1],C2 = todatetime(SplitLog[1]), C3 = SplitLog[2], UV = SplitLog[3]
    | summarize arg_max(C2,*) by tostring(UV)
    | project-away UV
    | project Log = strcat(tostring(C1), "|", cc, "|", C3, "|", UV1
```

Comment: I tried adding below one to my query.
| extend SplitLog = split(LogEntry, "|")
| project C1 = SplitLog[0], cc=SplitLog[1],C2 = todatetime(SplitLog[1]), C3 = SplitLog[2], UV = SplitLog[3], UV2=SplitLog[4], logerror=SplitLog[5];
| summarize arg_max(C2,*) by tostring(logerror)
| project-away logerror
| project log = strcat(tostring(C1), "|", cc, "|", C3, "|", UV, "|", UV2, "|", logerror  )

but some reason i was unable to run query from | summarize .  tried by including x before |summarize. but could not succeed.  please help what i am missing here

Comment: i am getting following error while running query,

'summarize' operator: Failed to resolve table or column expression named 'x'
If the issue persists, please open a support ticket. Request id: 041550f8-42a5-4c02-a1ac-6b2ff6f5e7a4

Comment: Donot include X remove x and try, If you re.move x then you should remove semicolon before that line, I guess now the error solves and you will get output see in edit section what to use.

Comment: it was ; causing the issue.  it worked like a charm now.  thank you so much Rithwik.   was struggling for two days.. thank you so much

Comment: I know it will work and I am glad that it did work for you @ramesh reddy

Comment: Thank you @RithwikBojja, i have similar request, hope you can answer. here is the link for new one    https://stackoverflow.com/a/76621591/13625511

Comment: Sure @ramesh reddy