# How to remove duplicate log entries in dynamic column through KQL Query

Tags: kql, azure-cloud-services, azure-monitor

I am trying to remove duplicate log entries from the dynamic column through KQL query. Below is the query.

```
    let ContainerIdList = KubePodInventory
    | where ContainerName contains "boss-logger"
    | where Namespace has "devns"
    | where ClusterId =~ '/subscriptions/abc1234-bcbd-3124-bc3a-524132fb1786645/resourcegroups/rg-aks-dev/providers/Microsoft.ContainerService/managedClusters/aksdevcluster'
    | distinct ContainerID;
    ContainerLog 
    | where ContainerID in (ContainerIdList)
    | where LogEntry matches regex "ERROR" 
    | project LogEntry
    | distinct LogEntry
```

However it does not removing the duplicate entries due to few characters although the error is same. please find screenshot output below.

[image]

if you see the above screenshot, "ERROR" is same but it does not getting removed due to those three characters and different timestamp.

How can we remove those duplicates based on content from ERROR: not timestamp and those three characters.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> How to remove duplicate log entries in dynamic column through KQL Query

I have reproduced in my environment and got expected results as below:

Firstly, I have taken a simple table like below:

```
LogEntry

2023-07-23 11:40:50,076 Error[xxx]
2023-07-23 11:42:50,400 Error[yyy]
2023-07-23 11:40:50,567 Error[xxx]
2023-07-23 14:40:50,011 Error[zzz]
```

[image]

I have used below query:

```
let x = datatable(LogEntry: string)
[
    "2023-07-23 11:40:50,076 Error[xxx]",
    "2023-07-23 11:42:50,400 Error[yyy]",
    "2023-07-23 11:40:50,567 Error[xxx]",
    "2023-07-23 14:40:50,011 Error[zzz]"
];
x
| extend SplitLog = split(LogEntry, " ")
| project C1 = todatetime(SplitLog[0]), C2 =SplitLog[1],cc=SplitLog[2], C3 = tostring(SplitLog[2])
| summarize arg_max(C1,*) by C3
| project-away C3
| project C2,cc,C1= todatetime(C1)
|extend SplitLog = split(C1, "T")
| project F1 = SplitLog[0],C2=C2,C3=cc
| project LogEntry = strcat(F1, " ", C2, " ", C3, " ")
```

[image]

Output:

[image]

[Fiddle](https://dataexplorer.azure.com/clusters/help/databases/SampleMetrics?query=H4sIAAAAAAAAA4WQXWuDMBSG7wX/w8ErHRGSaCs4vArt1e62O5GR2iAOP0rMWJT9%20CW2dna0LLnJx3Pec963EQo0ZHDkyuxDI/yXvtp1So4pDErWXRW4Tu46YJZHMY1CnIQ0AkLSGKcbjHCyhZ2Uvcy11oWH7qPUojHGF3Qcx4forLrZJv%20pxssAhFzQaZoKz3WKZ9fRrvMNQivRHeH11NTKuDIuB3u8OkTggRdY8iT7D1EqYMRAqjdhCFW3wl9Kc1wECBiF7PpCClSWv1damP9orj7H5q%20%205h7DZ9tyWU8CuKzeW659RtBTAIfRFK6GCPkX//NkOptmiJGb4Rixuo9MGnHw3m7t7a29lSfEaGakWZSV5ZpbArJiSpZc%20Xsyh2UzWA7ROb4fFmKX8EECAAA=)

Comment: thank @RithwikBojja,  here the problem is, we need to take whole data after ERROR which is not a single string , it may be some lines separated with commos(,), colon*:) ..etc we need to check all the data then remove the duplicate.  see below sample.
ERROR [org.jberet] (Batch Thread - 1) JBERET000007: Failed to run job consolidation, consolidate, org.jberet.job.model.Chunk@1c943fe7: com.riskshield.commons.tool.ConfigException: [63ca4d98-7982-4d96-b011-e13fa3948b7d] an error occurred during initialization of database 'JndiConnector [jndiName=java:jboss/datasources/RSS-Consolidation]': Connecti

Comment: Yeah, you need to integrate my query with your table and do that and you need to be more specific about input and it should not be in images

Comment: i tuned query little more and it worked. thanks you @RIthwikBojja

Comment: @rameshreddy Glad that it worked out for you.

Answer (score 0):

> *How to remove duplicate log entries in dynamic column?*

as the 'slots' in a `dynamic` property bag aren't ordered, you can use the [`dynamic_to_json()` function](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/data-explorer/kusto/query/dynamic-to-json-function) to convert the `dynamic` value into its canonical `string` form, then use `distinct` over the result.

for example:

```
datatable(d:dynamic)
[
    dynamic({"hello":"world","foo":"bar"}),
    dynamic({"world":"hello","bar":"foo"}),
    dynamic({"foo":"bar","hello":"world"}),
    dynamic({"bar":"foo","world":"hello"}),
]
| distinct result = dynamic_to_json(d)
```

| result |
| --- |
| {"foo":"bar","hello":"world"} |
| {"bar":"foo","world":"hello"} |

Comment: i need to remove three characters highlighted in screenshot, only these three characters are  changing although rest of the error is same.